# electrum, jaxx, and exodus

Tags: wallet, alternatives

I am interested in storing some bitcoin, etheruim, altcoins a year or some years.
I know hardware or paper wallets are the best choice, but as an absolute newbie, I decided to use a software offline wallet for simplicity( advice is welcomed).
Searching, I found Jaxx, Electrum, and Exodus as best choices.
As I read, I preferred electrum, but it supports only Bitcoins.
I need : (opensource offline-online user-controlled private keys, software wallet)
I am asking support for deciding on one of the following choices:
1. use an equivalent for electrum for multiple cryptocurrencies. And what to use multiBitHd, Jaxx, ...
2. start with bitcoin, when get some knowledge, create a paper wallet for multicurrencies?

Comment: Please use a title that provides insight on the content of your question.

Comment: Why do not consider more than one wallet? More safer I think.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to create a paper wallet for almost any Cryptocurrency :
https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@bad.r2017/how-to-create-a-paper-wallet-for-any-cryptocurrency-in-7-steps

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same questions for myself during last few days, up to date have found quite a lot info online :

- Recently there have been some troubles with security of Jaxx, more or less real, more or less rumours, anyway that has brought doubts about it. And it's not open-source (if to consider this as less trustworthy in blockchain community).
- Multibit project at all, including Multibit HD, is not more supported which was officially published on July 26th, 2017. That had been preсeded by massive users troubles all year 2017 before.
- On the other hand, Exodus is a newcomer and info about it looks mostly kind of sponsored, not yet many feedbacks from real users of Exodus. Although it intensively develops and gains recognition in blockchain community. It's not fully open-source but founder can make it that way in future, he mentioned about six months ago.
- So, till nowadays Electrum looks the most trustworthy desktop wallet in blockchain community, compared to the above mentioned. It's open-source, it has even portable version for Windows, and version for Linux, and version for Android. Yet it is only for bitcoin till today. We may just hope, who knows, maybe they will add some more cryptocoins into it sooner or later…
- Also they say there is another analogue of Electrum in all meanings, indeed more user-friendly for a newbie and more flexible and feature-rich. That is also well and long known software wallet Copay. And it is оnly for bitcoin too, and also there are no any talks if it can support some altcoins in future...

Among multi-currency wallets, I’ve found that actually Coinomi to be probably the best at present time. But it’s only on Android till today. Indeed they posted on GitHub in June 2017: Coinomi Desktops will be released soon for Windows, Linux and MacOS. Well, hope that will happen really soon…